# How can I 'double-dip' environment contents to an external file with expl3?

Tags: environments, expl3, content-replication

I'd like to capture the contents of a particular environment and copy them, verbatim (`n`- type expansion), to an external file already set up as an `iow` output stream.

My first thought was to simply create and use a token list variable like so:

```
\tl_new:N \l_resume_position_contents_tl
\NewDocumentEnvironment { position } { m } {
  ...
  \tl_set:Nn \l_resume_position_contents_tl
  \group_begin:
} {
  \group_end:
  \resume_do_stuff_with:N \l_resume_position_contents_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_resume_position_contents_tl
}
```

but I received the error

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.71 \end{position}
```

which I presume stems from a complete misunderstanding of the `\group_?:` functions.
Is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: No, you can't load the environment's content in that way; `\tl_set:Nn` is essentially `\def` and the brace around the argument *must* be explicit. There's no facility for this in `xparse`; use `environ`. However, you'll lose the line breaks, in this way. With `fancyvrb` you get facilities for verbatim writing to files. The LaTeX3 team still hasn't tackled the problem of `verbatim`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the info. It looks like this problem will have to be tackled with an `arara` (build-tool-shudder) / Perl mix until this is possible.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I know we need to do that! [`\tl_set:Nn` is `\edef` plus some magic, as I'm sure you know :-)]

Comment: @JosephWright I said *essentially*. `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to absorb the contents of an environment as a token list other than doing similarly to what the `environ` package does.

When you type `\tl_set:Nn \l_resume_position_contents_tl {...}`, you're telling TeX to do

```
\edef\l_resume_position_contents_tl{\unexpanded{...}}
```

which is, except for special cases, equivalent to

```
\def\l_resume_position_contents_tl{...}
```

TeX's syntax rules *require* that both braces are explicit; more specifically, `\def` (or `\edef`) *must* be followed by a control sequence (or active character); what's found after the control sequence, until getting to an explicit `{`<sub>1</sub> token is the “parameter text” (in the present case it's empty). When the brace has been found, TeX starts to store the token it finds as the replacement text, keeping track of brace nesting, ***without doing any expansion*** until arriving to the explicit `}`<sub>2</sub> token that matches the open brace. At that point the replacement text for the macro has been absorbed and TeX performs the assignment.

In the case of `\edef` there's an additional step: the absorbed replacement text is fully expanded before performing the assignment of the new meaning to the control sequence.

So any attempt such as

```
\newenvironment{foo}[1]
  {\def#1\bgroup}
  {\egroup}
```

is bound to failure, because `\bgroup` is not an explicit `{`<sub>1</sub> token, so it will be considered as part of the parameter text; let's see a simple example:

```
\begin{foo}{\baz}
Something
\end{foo}
```

When LaTeX finds `\begin{foo}` it essentially does `\begingroup\foo`, where the definition of `\foo` in this case is

```
\def\foo#1{\def#1\bgroup}
```

So after replacement we have

```
\def\baz\bgroup Something\end{foo}
```

Oh, no! We're defining `\baz` as having `\bgroup Something\end` as parameter text and `foo` as replacement text. And the environment will ***never*** be finished.

Using `\group_begin:` is not a solution, because this is `\begingroup` which is never a substitute for an open brace when the syntax rules require it (explicit or implicit).

So, what can you do? Use `environ`, because presently `xparse` doesn't offer similar functionality:

```
\usepackage{environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_resume_position_contents_tl
\NewEnviron { position } [1]
 {...
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_resume_position_contents_tl \BODY
  \resume_do_stuff_with:N \l_resume_position_contents_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_resume_position_contents_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```